# Trigger Parsley error on select of certain value in select-option dropdown

Tags: parsley.js

I am using parsley.js, I have native dropdown I have a certain list with a specific value to it, I want to trigger parsley error when value="noValue" (select) is selected.

```
<select required="true">
    <option value="NoValue">Select</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

so when the user selects "**select**(value="novalue")" parsley should trigger an error if required="true" and show an error message and append parsley-error class on the select/parsley-success if any other value is selected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [custom validators](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#custom) - they'll help to achieve that behaviour.

Or...if your option values are really single letters, you can use a regex-[pattern](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validator-pattern) such as `\w` for any single word-character. It will fail for "`NoValue`".